# Custom Cursor Stuck in top left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am running into a problem with making a custom cursor with blend mode exclusion. I have tried a couple techniques but for some odd reason, I added a cursor with blend modes, however it just shows up in the top left of my page and does not move. I want it to be the main cursor but do not know how to fix it.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ryanforprez/pen/vYyEWyL

```
    .cursor {
   position: fixed;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #ffff;

   mix-blend-mode: difference;
   z-index: 999;

  transition: transform 0.2s;
 }

 html,
 * {
 cursor: none;
pointer-events: none;

 }



<html>
<body onclick='window.location.href="work.html"'>
    
     </body>
 </html>

  <body>

    <div class="nav">

     <div class="name"><a href="work.html">Ryan Stewart</a></div>
<div class="info"><a href="information.html">Information</a></div>

</div>

        <div class="contact">   <a href="work.html">Click anywhere to enter.</a>
</div>



<marquee width="100%" direction="left" scrollamount="15" behavior="scroll">Ryan Stewart: Graphic Design, Art Direction, Letterform Design</marquee>
```

```
  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger-menu-button").click(function() {
  $(".main-box").toggleClass("main-box-clicked");
  $(".hamburger-box").toggleClass("hamburger-box-clicked");
  });

  var cursor = $(".cursor");

  $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
  cursor.css({
  top: e.clientY - cursor.height() / 2,
  left: e.clientX - cursor.width() / 2
  });
  });

  $(window)
  .mouseleave(function() {
  cursor.css({
    opacity: "0"
  });
  })
 .mouseenter(function() {
  cursor.css({
    opacity: "1"
  });
 });

 $(".link")
.mouseenter(function() {
  cursor.css({
    transform: "scale(3.2)"
  });
})
.mouseleave(function() {
  cursor.css({
    transform: "scale(1)"
  });
});

 $(window)
.mousedown(function() {
  cursor.css({
    transform: "scale(.2)"
  });
})
.mouseup(function() {
  cursor.css({
    transform: "scale(1)"
  });
});
 });</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple `<body>` tags?

Comment: I just changed it in my codepen, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you have multiple opening and closing body and html tags, short, because your code is chaos. Following a correctly-indented, clenaed-up and working version :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".hamburger-menu-button").click(function() {
      $(".main-box").toggleClass("main-box-clicked");
      $(".hamburger-box").toggleClass("hamburger-box-clicked");
      });

      var cursor = $(".cursor");

      $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
      cursor.css({
      top: e.clientY - cursor.height() / 2,
      left: e.clientX - cursor.width() / 2
      });
      });

      $(window)
      .mouseleave(function() {
      cursor.css({
        opacity: "0"
      });
      })
     .mouseenter(function() {
      cursor.css({
        opacity: "1"
      });
     });

     $(".link")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      cursor.css({
        transform: "scale(3.2)"
      });
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      cursor.css({
        transform: "scale(1)"
      });
    });

     $(window)
    .mousedown(function() {
      cursor.css({
        transform: "scale(.2)"
      });
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
      cursor.css({
        transform: "scale(1)"
      });
    });
     });
```

```css
.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #cccc;
  
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

* {
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="name">
        <a href="work.html">Ryan Stewart</a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <a href="information.html">Information</a>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="contact">
    <a href="work.html">Click anywhere to enter.</a>
</div>
<marquee width="100%" direction="left" scrollamount="15" behavior="scroll">Ryan Stewart: Graphic Design, Art Direction, Letterform Design</marquee>
<div class="cursor"></div>
```